# how to pull the last record in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi I have a select clause used in a sub query after doing a Order by on few columns i get multiple rows as an output from the subquery.
but i need just the last record to get returned from the subquery.so that i can process it in the main query.

```
Select T.C1, T1.C4 as emp from
 (Select C1,C4 from t1 group by C1,C4  order by c1,c2,c3 ) T
```

the sub query returns

```
C1             C4
bal             1
Env             1
John            2
```

all i need is just JOHN, 2 as output

Answer (score 2):

In your case the simplest way would be to use the [LAST](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions083.htm#i1000905) (it's not well named) clause:

```
select max(c1) keep (dense_rank last order by c1, c2, c3) as c1
     , max(c4) keep (dense_rank last order by c1, c2, c3) as c4
  from t1
```

This selects the last record in the order specified and as defined by your aggregate function. MAX is just an affection here; MIN would work equally well.

I would recommend [Rob van Wijk's article](http://rwijk.blogspot.co.uk/2012/09/keep-clause.html).

Comment: You should change the alias `c1` to `c4` in second line.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand @snyder?

Comment: Ah, thanks @beherenow. It's why copying and pasting is the root of all evil.

Comment: Hello Ben. im using a funcation to perform this it throws me an error 
ORA-14552: cannot perform a DDL, commit or rollback inside a query or DML

Comment: Your error is nothing to do with the SELECT statement in my answer. You can't perform DDL or DML (create table/insert etc) inside a function that you're using in a SELECT statement. You need to change your model.

Comment: Hi Balahi, this is nothing to do with cursors. Please [ask another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) if you have one; however, before you do check to see whether you have any DDL or DML in your function, for e.g. UPDATE, INSERT, MERGE, CREATE, TRUNCATE. You _cannot_ use these in a function that is being called from SQL (i.e. within a SELECT statement). This is what the error message says.

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest method is using `rownum` with a subquery.  This requires reversing your sort order:

```
Select T.C1, T1.C4 as emp
from (Select C1, C4
      from t1
      group by C1, C4
      order by c1 desc, c2 desc, c3 desc
     ) T
where rownum = 1;
```

I do note, however, that your query is syntactically incorrect, because you are ordering by non-aggregated columns.